# Add a dictionary to a dictionary

Tags: python, dictionary

I'd like if it would be possible to do something like this :

```
pre_dict = {'pictures'}
to_add = {'extension' : 'jpeg'}
'pictures'.update(to_add)?
```

So that I could end up getting this :

```
pre_dict = {'pictures' : {'extension' : 'jpeg'}
```

And add other elements such as this :

```
'pictures'.update({'size':10000})
```

To finally get this:

```
 pre_dict = {'pictures' : {'extension' : 'jpeg', 'size':10000}
```

Thank you !

Comment: Also, `pre_dict` is actually a set

Comment: So what's wrong with `pre_dict['pictures'] = to_add` and `pre_dict['pictures'].update({'size':10000})` or `pre_dict['pictures']['size'] = 10000`.

Answer (score 4):

yes, define your `pre_dict` value as an empty dictionary (it is currently a `set`):

```
pre_dict = {'pictures':{}}
to_add = {'extension' : 'jpeg'}
pre_dict['pictures'].update(to_add)
pre_dict['pictures'].update({'size':10000})  # your other update operation
print(pre_dict)
```

result:

```
{'pictures': {'size': 10000, 'extension': 'jpeg'}}
```

Note that `update` is overkill to add a single value (but useful for inputs like `{'extension' : 'jpeg', 'size':10000}`). For one value just do:

```
pre_dict['pictures']['size'] = 10000
```

Comment: Another option (rather than defining a single value `to_add` dictionary and using `update()` to add it) is to directly set the desired value in the inner dictionary with `pre_dict['pictures']['extension'] = 'jpeg'`.